# Mongodb [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection called: `ec2_list-07-26-2020`

If I try to do typical operations on it like `find()` or `validate()` I get this error:

```
db.ec2_list-07-26-2020.find()
2020-07-26T20:17:16.845-0400 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal :
@(shell):1:18
```

So I created a test collection called: `audit00`. When I do the same on that collection it works fine:

```
 db.audit00.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f1e1e02807681425a06fa07"), "writeConcern" : "yes", "ordered" : "True" }
```

And:

```
db.audit00.validate()
{
        "ns" : "aws_inventories.audit00",
        "nInvalidDocuments" : NumberLong(0),
        "nrecords" : 1,
        "nIndexes" : 1,
        "keysPerIndex" : {
                "_id_" : 1
        },
        "valid" : true,
        "warnings" : [
                "Some checks omitted for speed. use {full:true} option to do more thorough scan."
        ],
        "errors" : [ ],
        "extraIndexEntries" : [ ],
        "missingIndexEntries" : [ ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Is there something wrong in the way that I'm naming my collections that needs to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your collection name. It doesn't violate any [MongoDB naming restriction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions).

Following command should work in mongo `shell`:

```
const col = db.getCollection("ec2_list-07-26-2020")
col.find()
```

OR

```
db["ec2_list-07-26-2020"].find()
```